# How to create a required Boolean field in recent Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to reproduce:

1. Create a Django model `Foo` with a `django.db.models.BooleanField()`, let's call it `bar`.
2. Create an extremely basic serializer class with `Meta.fields = "__all__"`.
3. *Update:* Create a `PolymorphicSerializer` on top of the existing serializer and a view+path using the `PolymorphicSerializer`.
4. Try to POST a new `Foo` **without** supplying a `bar`.

What happens: The request returns HTTP 201 Created and includes `bar=False`.

What should happen: The request should obviously fail, with a response indicating that `bar` is required.

I have a required `IntegerField` on the model as well, and trying to POST instance data without *that* parameter *does* result in a "required" error message.

I'm not using Django forms, so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49622241/96588) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3410954/96588) are not duplicates. I've tried [this workaround](https://notes.noumenal.es/required-by-default/), but `del kwargs['required']` fails with "KeyError: 'required'". [This other workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30953607/96588) doesn't seem to do anything, possibly because the field is defined on the model as well. Ditto for [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39835680/96588).

Using djangorestframework==3.9.2 and django==2.1.7.

Comment: Could be a bug with the serialization code in DRF, it might be incorrectly interpreting the lack of a value as 'not true' and hence 'false'.
You could try overrdiing this in the serializer to be a NullableBoolenField (it's been a while so i might have the field name wrong) which should understand null state, and then write a validator for that field that throws a validationError `if val is None`

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** This is not an answer to the OP, but I'm explaining why DRF has this behavior

---

In short, ***this happens only if you try to POST through HTML form ([DRF Web API Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjTkd.png))***. If you try through [POSTMAN Console, it will raise the Validation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1Pe3.png)

---

## Why this??

If you inspect the type of **`request.data`** in both case, it will be as

```
| Request Source    | Input data type   |
|------------------ |-----------------  |
| DRF HTML Input    | QueryDict         |
| POSTMAN API call  | dict              |
```

#### Where the change happens?

The [**`get_value()`** method of **`Field`**](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L423) class causing the behavior. In that, a check happens as,

```
if html.is_html_input(dictionary):
    ....... do something
```

**from that if clause, the EMPTY/BLANK value became `False`**

---

---

## Solution

Create custom boolean field for your serializer override it's  **`get_value()`** method

```
from rest_framework.fields import empty


class CustomBooleanField(serializers.BooleanField):
    def get_value(self, dictionary):
        return dictionary.get(self.field_name, empty)


class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bar = CustomBooleanField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Foo
```

---

## Screenshots

**1. DRF Web API console**
[image]

**2. POSTMAN API Console**
[image]

Comment: This is happening when running a Django test case.

Comment: My answer not helping much?

Comment: Anyway, can you share the minimal test code that I can simulate the error?

Answer (score 1):

Add `extra_kwargs` to your `ModelSerializer` as suggested below.

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = "__all__"
        extra_kwargs = {'bar': {'required': True}}
```

This set `required=True` argument in `bar` field.

If you have any further questions than please ask to the comments section.

Comment: Beat me to it, decided to install all the matching versions and test the code first... this does indeed work. response is ```{
  "bar": [
    "This field is required."
  ]
}```

Comment: As I mentioned, this was one of the things I tried. I'll give it another go.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Maybe because of the `PolymorphicSerializer` used for this endpoint - the required field is only on one of the classes.